# Input text value in url after clicking button

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how to input text value from a text field and adding it into an url after click Search button. So far I am not able to make that the value from input shows in the url. So what I have is this:

```
<input type="text" id="myText" value="Mickey">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Search</button>
```

and the javascript:

```
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
}
var sourceCode = '<a href="http://www.domain.com/cat/' + x ">' + '<img src="' + imageBase + image + '" width="'+sizes[0]+'" height="'+sizes[1]+'"/></a>'
```

How can I get x value to be showing the value from the input text field?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you want this `<a>` element to be shown?

Comment: You can start by moving the end curly after the var sourceCode but then you also need to do something with the x - for example `location="http://www.domain.com/cat/" + x` instead of the `a href`

Answer (score 1):

`x` does get the value of the input field, but your string build of `sourceCode` is riddled with errors (`x` is inside the double-quotes, `image` is undefined, etc). It also lies outside `myFunction()` so `x` is undefined too, and in any case will be executed before you click. If you comment out that line and add `alert(x)` inside `myFunction()` you can see that you do indeed capture the input, but the script fails and stops running.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
    var sourceCode = '<a href="http://www.domain.com/cat/' + x + '">' + '<img src="' + imageBase + image + '" width="'+sizes[0]+'" height="'+sizes[1]+'"/></a>';
}
```